# Update div id using dynamic variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I thought that this would be easy but this does not work, though it doesn't give an error either.

I have some text on my web page with id's display1, display2, display3....

When I try to update them in a loop like this nothing happens.

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++){
('display' + i).innerHTML = "123";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You miss the $ to call the selector with jquery.

Comment: `document.getElementById('display'+i).innerHTML = "123";`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++){
document.getElementById('display' + i).innerHTML = "123";
}
```

Or (better practice), I recommend you give all your display elements one class name and

```
displays=document.getElementsByClassName('newClassNameOfDisplays');
for (i = 1; i < displays.length+1; i++){
displays[i].innerHTML = "123";
}
```

Your code didn't work because `String().innerHTML` doesn't exist, you had to get the element from the DOM rather than create a string. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're not properly selecting the elements, try this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById('display' + i).innerHTML = '123';
}
```

**JSFiddle Example**

**http://jsfiddle.net/tLPkj/3/**

Comment: Why do you need to wrap it in an anonymous function? That is completely unnecessary. So is using `["display", j].join("")`. Can't you just use `"display" + j`?

Comment: Yes it's unnecessary in this case since it's synchronous. It's a personal preference.

Comment: Updated answer. User `asimes` deserves credit for answering first.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given in the comments are probably both correct (not sure why they weren't posted as answers).  What is happening in your code is that you are creating a string (`('display')+i`), and then creating a new property called `innerHTML` on that string, and then setting the value of the new `innerHTML` property to `""`.

The reason this doesn't give an error is that (almost) everything in JavaScript is an object, and you can set properties on objects at will.  For example `("Hello").description="a greeting"` is a perfectly valid JavaScript statement.